# NEO4J: What is a good practice to store a returned path with addtional information (e.g. a concrete train run in a metro network)?

Tags: neo4j, path

Say there is a **metro network** with **n stops**, each represented by a NEO4J **node** with the **rail connection** between two stops represented by a **relationship**.

I wish to store the fact `train_run` that e.g. **Train 01234** ran from **stop n1** to **stop n4** via stops **n2** and **n3** at a certain time. I wish to store this information in a manner that must be consistent with the existing DB information regarding the metro network, hence preventing the creation of any `train_run` along a path that doesn't exist (e.g jumping stop n3).

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Is there a useful way to store in the Neo4J DB a path p returned from that DB jointly with the properties `.train_number` and `time_stamp`? Or should I consider a totally different approach?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Train network]

you can use a structure like this to represent your data . Train to source and destination is optional .That will just help you in finding number of trains between source and destination efficiently . If there are multiple trains between two stops , you need to have multiple relations , one for each train no.